# Arbitrarily long Parallel.For loops in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Parallel.For allows loops with a max iteration of long.MaxValue

```
Parallel.For(long fromInclusive, long toExclusive, Action<long> body)
{
}
```

but what if I need to perform a Parallel loop which would have vastly more iterations than long.MaxValue?

E.G. I have a function which returns the number of required iterations as a BigInteger (because long and ulong are not big enough).

Would I have to "roll my own" Parallel.For implementation. My gut feeling is that this is going to be bad practice!

EDIT: Based on various comments...I think I have bitten off more than I can chew!

Comment: Can't you use `Parallel.ForEach` in case you are dealing with enumerations?

Comment: @RV1987, if a BigInteger can be expressed as an enumerable, then yes, I guess I could!...if you know how to do that...please do let me know!

Comment: You are performing more than 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 iterations?

Comment: Let's do a quick calculation here: a loop with empty body from 0 to int.MaxValue takes about 1 second on my machine. So linearly extrapolating (from 0 -> long.MaxValue) would take 2^31 seconds or about 68 years... Even on a 64 core machine and a perfectly parallelizable algorithm it would still take you... a long time.

Comment: You want to factor a 1024 byte number. So, potentially, you want to iterate over a number that might be as large as 10^154? (2^512) Say you can work 10^9 items per second, thats only going to take you about 10^137 years. Even if you increase your compute power/algortihm efficiency 1000 fold, that's still 10^134 years. Rethink might be important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @davenewza, but if you *must*, this can be a solution

```
Parallel.ForEach(BigIntSequence(1,10), (i) => Console.WriteLine(i));

public IEnumerable<BigInteger> BigIntSequence(BigInteger min,BigInteger max)
{
    BigInteger bi = min;
    while (bi<max)
    {
        yield return bi;
        bi += 1;     
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, but as stated, the result is an extremely long process!

Answer (score 4):

`Int64.MaxValue` is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

If you need to perform more iterations then you really need to reconsider your design.

Comment: The issue is, I am loading in a byte[] of 1024 bytes into BigInteger and treating it as a number, then I need to loop from 0 to the value of the BigInteger to find all of it's factors....I cannot think of how this can be achieved, and admittedly, this is going to be damn slow!

Comment: @activewerx It may be obvious, but just thought I'd mention it: If you are factoring you will only need to loop to sqrt(yourBigNumber)